# \text command strangely fails

Tags: math-mode, errors, equations

I wrote a command like this:

```
${\cal F}_n=^{\text df}$
```

but at `\text` it gives an error.
I wish to write `df` above `=` with `\text` but it doesn't go through.
How should I fix it?

However `$\textbf$` works fine, but I do not wish boldface, just text.

Comment: Did you load `amsmath`?

Comment: No. WHY? But it works fine with it.

Comment: `$\mathcal{F}_n =^{\mathrm{def}}$`

Comment: `\text` is a command defined in package `amstext`, which is usually loaded via `amsmath`.

Comment: also `\cal` isn't defined by default, it is defined by some classes for compatibility with documents from the 1980s. the latex syntax is `\mathcal{F}`